# Why do my TCP clients fail to connect to my server with a socket exception when stress-testing it with many connections

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-core, port

When stress-testing a TCP server of mine with a large number of connections, I figured that connection requests will throw a SocketException after some time. The exception displays randomly either

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

or

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

as its message.

This happens usually but randomly after some seconds and some tens of thousands of connects and disconnects. To connect, I use the local end point `IPEndPoint clientEndPoint = new(IPAddress.Any, 0);`, which I believe would give me the next free ephemeral port.

To isolate the issue, I wrote this simple program that runs both a TCP server and many parallel clients for a simple counter:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new();
CancellationToken cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

const int serverPort = 65000;
const int counterRequestMessage = -1;
const int randomCounterResponseMinDelay = 10; //ms
const int randomCounterResponseMaxDelay = 1000; //ms
const int maxParallelCounterRequests = 10000;

#region server

int counterValue = 0;

async void RunCounterServer()
{
    TcpListener listener = new(IPAddress.Any, serverPort);
    listener.Start(maxParallelCounterRequests);
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        HandleCounterRequester(await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync(cancellationToken));
    }

    listener.Stop();
}

async void HandleCounterRequester(TcpClient client)
{
    await using NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    Memory<byte> memory = new byte[sizeof(int)];

    //read requestMessage
    await stream.ReadAsync(memory, cancellationToken);
    int requestMessage = BitConverter.ToInt32(memory.Span);
    Debug.Assert(requestMessage == counterRequestMessage);

    //increment counter
    int updatedCounterValue = Interlocked.Add(ref counterValue, 1);
    Debug.Assert(BitConverter.TryWriteBytes(memory.Span, updatedCounterValue));

    //wait random timeout
    await Task.Delay(GetRandomCounterResponseDelay());

    //write back response
    await stream.WriteAsync(memory, cancellationToken);

    client.Close();
    client.Dispose();
}

int GetRandomCounterResponseDelay()
{
    return Random.Shared.Next(randomCounterResponseMinDelay, randomCounterResponseMaxDelay);
}

RunCounterServer();

#endregion

IPEndPoint clientEndPoint = new(IPAddress.Any, 0);
IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), serverPort);
ReaderWriterLockSlim isExceptionEncounteredLock = new(LockRecursionPolicy.NoRecursion);
bool isExceptionEncountered = false;

async Task RunCounterClient()
{
    try
    {
        int counterResponse;
        using (TcpClient client = new(clientEndPoint))
        {
            await client.ConnectAsync(serverEndPoint, cancellationToken);

            await using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
            {
                Memory<byte> memory = new byte[sizeof(int)];

                //send counter request
                Debug.Assert(BitConverter.TryWriteBytes(memory.Span, counterRequestMessage));
                await stream.WriteAsync(memory, cancellationToken);

                //read counter response
                await stream.ReadAsync(memory, cancellationToken);
                counterResponse = BitConverter.ToInt32(memory.Span);
            }

            client.Close();
        }

        isExceptionEncounteredLock.EnterReadLock();
        //log response if there was no exception encountered so far
        if (!isExceptionEncountered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(counterResponse);
        }

        isExceptionEncounteredLock.ExitReadLock();
    }
    catch (SocketException exception)
    {
        bool isFirstEncounteredException = false;

        isExceptionEncounteredLock.EnterWriteLock();

        //log exception and note that one was encountered if it is the first one
        if (!isExceptionEncountered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            isExceptionEncountered = true;
            isFirstEncounteredException = true;
        }

        isExceptionEncounteredLock.ExitWriteLock();

        //if this is the first exception encountered, rethrow it
        if (isFirstEncounteredException)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}

async void RunParallelCounterClients()
{
    SemaphoreSlim clientSlotCount = new(maxParallelCounterRequests, maxParallelCounterRequests);

    async void RunCounterClientAndReleaseSlot()
    {
        await RunCounterClient();
        clientSlotCount.Release();
    }

    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await clientSlotCount.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
        RunCounterClientAndReleaseSlot();
    }
}

RunParallelCounterClients();

while (true)
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
    if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
    {
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        break;
    }
}
```

My initial guess is, that I run out of ephemeral ports because I somehow do not free them correctly. I just `Close()` and `Dispose()` my `TcpClient`s in both my client and server code when a request is finished. I thought that would automatically release the port, but when I use `netstat -ab` in a console, it gives me countless entries like this, even after closing the application:

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:65000        kubernetes:59996       TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:65000        kubernetes:59997       TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:65000        kubernetes:59998       TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:65000        kubernetes:59999       TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:65000        kubernetes:60000       TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:65000        kubernetes:60001       TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:65000        kubernetes:60002       TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:65000        kubernetes:60003       TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:65000        kubernetes:60004       TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:65000        kubernetes:60005       TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:65000        kubernetes:60006       TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:65000        kubernetes:60007       TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:65000        kubernetes:60009       TIME_WAIT
```

Also, my PC sometimes gets a lot of stutter some time after I exit the application. I assume this is due to Windows cleaning up my leaked port usage?

So I wonder, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "*Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted*" - likely **port exhaustion**. Just because you use ephemeral ports on the local side doesn't mean they are infinite. Add some delays between connects to give closed ports time to release. "*No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it*" - the server can hold only so many clients in its backlog at a time. If more clients try to connect than the backlog can hold, they will be rejected. Have clients attempt to reconnect a few times (with delay in between) before giving up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. ... My initial guess is, that I run out of ephemeral ports because I somehow do not free them correctly.

TIME_WAIT is a perfectly normal state each TCP connection will enter when the connection is actively closed, i.e. explicitly calling close after sending the data or implicitly closing when exiting the application. See this diagram (source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tcp_state_diagram_fixed.svg):

[image: TCP state diagram]

It will take some timeout to leave the TIME_WAIT state and enter CLOSED. As long as the connection is in TIME_OUT the specific combination of source ip, port and destination ip,port cannot be used for new connections. This effectively limits the number of connections possible within some time from one specific IP address to another specific IP. Note that typical servers don't run into such limits since they get many connections from different system, and from each source IP only a few connections.

There is not much one can do about this except not actively closing the connection. If the other side triggers the connection first (sending FIN) and one continues with this close (ACKing the FIN and sending own FIN) then no TIME_WAIT will happen. Of course in your specific scenario of a single client and a single server this will just shift the problem to the server.

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

This has another reason. The server does a `listen` on the socket and gives the intended size of the backlog (the OS might will probably not use exactly this value). This backlog is used to accept new TCP connections in the OS kernel and the server will the call `accept` to get these accepted TCP connections. If the server calls `accept` less often than new connections get established the backlog will fill up. And once the backlog is full the server will refuse new connection, resulting in the error you see. In other words: this happens if the server is not able to keep up with the client.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer!
This clears up a lot for me. 
I assume having the server not actively close the connection and just wait for the client to close it before exciting its handler thread is therefore the most sensible thing to do? 
I mean since I assume the server to need much more connection than the client in regular usage.

And regarding the backlog, I initialized it to the maximum number of parallel connections, so I thought this would be save, but since you wrote the OS may not respect this number exactly, maybe the number was just too large for my Windows system.